# Export PostGIS line to AutoCAD with graphical direction information

Tags: postgis, gdal, ogr2ogr, autocad

Some time ago I managed to **export from PostgreSQL to AutoCAD DXF format a line (LINESTRING) using ogr2ogr program with a PostgreSQL Query**, and it works (I can visualise it by the QuantumGIS).

**Now** I really need to, in some way, **export graphical information about the direction of that line**, like little arrows on the line.

First I tried with the OGR Style Feature "Symbol", trying to include a query field OGR_STYLE with the content similar to `SYMBOL(c:#00FF00,id:"points.sym-45,ogr-sym-7",a:X.xx)`. But I realised that the DXF driver does not understand and draw this features.

So then I changed radically my idea and now I am trying to export, apart from the line, another **DXF file with little triangle polygons simulating the direction of the line**, the little arrows.

- First I **get all the points of the line** by PostGIS ST_DumpPoints function
- Then I **get every point with its next point** with WINDOW PostgreSQL method.
- Then I **get the direction from the point to its next point** by PostGIS ST_Azimuth function
- And finally, to draw the little arrow triangle polygon, I need to **get the 2 other points** from the final one of the pair, locating them to X distance back from the original, with the direction obtained multiplied to -1 and +X and -X (respectively for each of the 2 new points).
- Then I would be able to **make the little triangles** with that 3 points by PostGIS ST_MakePolygon function

Here it is the idea of Query that I would use with the ogr2ogr command  -sql parameter, like `ogr2ogr -f DXF line_directions.dxf "PG:host=192.168.1.* user=**** password=**** dbname=****" -sql "THE QUERY"`

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[point1, point2, point3])) AS the_geom
FROM (
    SELECT *, next_point AS point1, ST_Project(next_point, 10, ((orientation + 1) * (-1))) AS point2, ST_Project(next_point, 10, ((orientation - 1) * (-1))) AS point3
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ST_Distance(point, next_point) AS distance, ST_Azimuth(point, next_point) AS orientation
        FROM (
            SELECT geom_id, path[1] AS path, geom AS point, lead(geom) OVER (PARTITION BY geom_id ORDER BY path ASC) AS next_point
            FROM (
                SELECT a.geom_id, (ST_DumpPoints(a.geom)).* 
                FROM (
                    SELECT id AS geom_id, line AS geom 
                    FROM my_lines_table
                    WHERE line IS NOT NULL
                ) AS a
            ) b
            ORDER BY path ASC
        ) c
        WHERE next_point IS NOT NULL
    ) d
) e;
```

I know that in PostGIS 2.0 there is the ST_Project function that would help me to do it but I am working with the **PostGIS 1.5.3** and I can't upgrade it.

Any help?

Comment: OpenJUMP PLUS has a DXF read/write driver and it can also read data from PostGIS. From the schema that OpenJUMP creates for output I got an idea to utilize fields "TEXT" and "TEXT_ROTATION". Read points and computed rotations from PostGIS, insert text ">" and rotate the Greater than character with "TEXT_ROTATION". Save into DXF with OpenJUMP.

Comment: Thank you @user30184, I did not had this idea. The main problem is that I need to be able to, once exported, visualise it in an easy way with AutoCAD. And I need to make this export an automatic process with PostGIS (PostgreSQL) and GDAL ogr2ogr command.

Comment: I do not know anything about DXF but perhaps you could slip the text blocks with some script in correct places. One block looks like `TEXT
  8
New
 39
0.000000
 10
122.0000
 20
163.0000
  1
>
 50
10.000000
  0`  The second last row "10.000000" is the rotation angle.

Comment: I don't understand exactly your idea, I don't exactly see the execution of the script, like I said I would like to manage to do it only with the ogr2ogr command and the -sql parameter with the PostgreSQL(PostGIS) Query. I neither know much about DXF, I used to check in the OGR DXF information (http://www.gdal.org/drv_dxf.html) to get some idea but there isn't much options. Thank you again.

Comment: Forget my idea about making a skript that injects the arrows inside DXF that is initially created with ogr2ogr. So the alternative is what you suggested in the very beginning and try to create another DXF layer with only arrows. It could still be possible to write rotated characters out because driver manual says `Point features with LABEL styling are written as MTEXT entities based on the styling information.` But probably your triangle idea is better.

Comment: You are right but I tried it and the driver only gets the text, not the style/rotation of that text. So, from the style string `LABEL(f:"Arial, Helvetica", s:12pt, t:"Hello World!", a:3)` it only understand the `t:"Hello World!"` and copy that content to the Text DXF object attribute. About the triangle idea I'm afraid the only way is to upgrade to PostGIS 2.0 and use the ST_Project function..

Comment: Well, if ogr2ogr does write the text it might be possible to add the rotation parameter with text editor by using trial/error and search/replace and the OpenJUMP example from above. Search for "Hello World!" and add NewLine - 50 - NewLine - 45.00 after it. If Hello World rotates 45 degrees you have at least learned something. Probably it does not help much with your final task but hopefully makes you feel good.

Comment: what software will the dxf be visualized in? or will it only be used for processing? Why not just decorate the line in that software. Most GIS already has this capability.

Comment: I know @BradNesom, it will be visualized and printed by AutoCAD, I don't have it in my own to check it but the final user of that DXF assured me it is not possible to generate that visual arrows from a line in his AutoCAD. I have the QuantumGIS and there I know it is possible. Right know I'm trying the impossible, to get the little arrow triangle 2 other points needed by trigonometry, by the (x,y) of the original point and the azimuth of the line direction.. Hope my hair will not fall before I manage it..

Comment: even dumb ole autocad knows the angle /direction of a line. If you can write it it can do it. my concern would be the clutter and the handling of putting arrows in the drawing. they would need to be on a different layer or you would not be able to use the drawing without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I finally got the drawing of the lines direction arrows by a little bit of **trigonometry in the PostgreSQL(PostGIS) Query** that generates the geometries for the ogr2ogr command to export it to the DXF file.

The arrow triangle I get is not perfect, it has the tail a little bit moved but it will be enough for my needs.

- First I **get all the points of the line** by PostGIS ST_DumpPoints function
- Then I **get every point with its next point** with WINDOW PostgreSQL method
- Then I **get the direction from the next point to the point** by PostGIS ST_Azimuth and degrees functions, so I know the **direction where to create the 2 other points**
- Then I **get also the middle point between the 2 points** of the sub-line
- Then I **create multiplier constants with a case expression on the value of direction(orientation)** got by the ST_Azimuth+degrees function
- Then, to draw the little arrow triangle polygon, I **get the 2 other points** from the middle one of the line, locating them to X distance back from the original, by **adding or substracting the constants I got to the coordinates X,Y of the middle point**.
- Then I finally **make the little triangles with that 3 points** by PostGIS ST_MakePolygon and ST_MakeLine function

Here it is **The Query** that I will use with the ogr2ogr command -sql parameter, like `ogr2ogr -f DXF line_directions.dxf "PG:host=*.*.*.* user=**** password=**** dbname=****" -sql "THE QUERY"`:

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[point1, point2, point3, point1]))::geometry as the_geom
FROM (
  SELECT middle_point as point1, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(middle_point) + x_mult - (y_mult * 0.25::float), ST_Y(middle_point) + y_mult + (x_mult * 0.25::float)), ST_SRID(middle_point)) as point2, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(middle_point) + x_mult + (y_mult * 0.25::float), ST_Y(middle_point) + y_mult - (x_mult * 0.25::float)), ST_SRID(middle_point)) as point3
  FROM (
    SELECT geom_orig, middle_point, distance, orientation,
           (case when (orientation <= 90::float) then (orientation / 90::float) * 1::float when ((orientation > 90::float) and (orientation <= 180::float)) then ((180::float - orientation) / 90::float) * 1::float when ((orientation > 180::float) and (orientation <= 270::float)) then ((orientation - 180::float) / 90::float) * -1::float else ((360::float - orientation) / 90::float) * -1::float end) * 10::float as x_mult,
           (case when (orientation <= 90::float) then ((90::float - orientation) / 90::float) * 1::float when ((orientation > 90::float) and (orientation <= 180::float)) then ((orientation - 90::float) / 90::float) * -1::float when ((orientation > 180::float) and (orientation <= 270::float)) then ((270::float - orientation) / 90::float) * -1::float else ((orientation - 270::float) / 90::float) * 1::float end) * 10::float as y_mult
    FROM (
      SELECT geom_orig, point, next_point, ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(ARRAY[point, next_point])) as middle_point, ST_Distance(point, next_point) as distance, degrees(ST_Azimuth(next_point, point)) AS orientation
      FROM (
        SELECT geom_orig, path[1] as path, geom as point, lead(geom) OVER (PARTITION BY geom_orig ORDER BY path ASC) as next_point
        FROM (
          SELECT geom as geom_orig, (ST_DumpPoints(geom::geometry)).*
          FROM (
                SELECT line AS geom 
                FROM my_lines_table
                WHERE line IS NOT NULL
          ) a
        ) b
      ) c
    ) d
    WHERE distance >= (10 * 2) 
  ) e
) ogr;
```

As I said, PostgreSQL with PostGIS version 2.0 would simplify a lot this Query by the function ST_Project, until I can upgrade here I have my Query:)

Thank you all for your comments and help:)